# "HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure" for dotnet core 2.1 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, .net-core

From error log:-
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

As I understand, I need to make changes in app.config to match the versions, but I cannot find app.config.

My web.config (Posting the entire file incase any error is found)

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>

      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <!-- When deploying on Azure, make sure that "dotnet" is installed and the path to it is registered in the PATH environment variable or specify the full path to it -->
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="23:00:00" processPath="D:\******ini_nc\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\Nop.Core.dll" arguments="dotnet" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="True" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" startupTimeLimit="3600">
      <environmentVariables />
    </aspNetCore>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="true" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: what is the version(s) of .net core on the server where you host and what is the version in your code (i assume the second is 2.1)?

Comment: The values of `processPath` and `arguments` should be reversed.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane hi, both are 2.1, afaik.
Running a quick "dotnet --info" results in
.NET Core SDK:
 Version:   2.1.300

Host:
  Version: 2.1.0
  Commit:  caa7b7e2ba

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.300 
.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0

Comment: @LexLi that still results in the same error.

Comment: You can easily miss details in Microsoft documentation and make multiple mistakes. Run a report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html and attach it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend making changes on files such as web.config that are auto-generated on publishing. Here is a small example of how the web.config of .net framework is replaced in .net core

- Project level configuration (such as .net core or c# version) can be set from the .csproj file
- Web launch related configurations (such as linking your `IConfiguration` to a custom source) can be set up from the program.cs
- The middleware and application related configurations (such as mapping your db connection string) can be set up from the startup cs class

In your case, check if your server has the required runtime. If possible install the required .net core runtime from dot.net/core in the server. If you can't install this due to permissions or something, you can either downgrade your app version **or** use a self-contained publish.

**Downgrading app version**

Keep in mind this means you would lose version specific code. This isn't recommended if you already have a lot of code that might be version specific. This can be done by updating your .csprog file. Unlike .net framework. It is considered clean and safe to update this file in .net core.

** self-contained publish**

This option designed to work on systems without any .net core installed. It works by creating published files that contain all .net core runtime related files into a huge publish folder. So, keep in mind the publish folder would be huge. Have a look at this for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the reply.
As it happens, I ran the --info command on my powershell and this was the output

https://pastebin.com/nEFAPuKX

So, I'm not sure that it's a versioning error. I do not intend to downgrade app version or do a self-contained publish since I'm new to ASP.NET

Unless downgrading in core is as easy as making changes to .csproj.
Could you elaborate more on that?